# Split data into chunks and add numbers to results

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
def multi():
   jobs = []
   r = open('raw.txt', 'r', 16777216).read().split('\n')
   for i in r:
      p = mp.Process(target=all, args=(i,))
      jobs.append(p)
      p.start()
```

Each line of raw.txt is URL

Please explain how I can modify multi() to

a) split raw.txt into chunks (say, 10 lines each) and apply all() to each chunk and

b) return number of processed lines / chunks in the end

Thank you,

Comment: I would use a generator to return lines in chunks of whatever amount you specify. That done, your other requirements are trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `itertools` package it has plenty of useful things.

```
>>> with open('input.txt', 'w') as f:
...   for i in xrange(998):
...     f.write(uuid.uuid4().get_hex() + '\n')
... 
>>> 
>>> from itertools import groupby, count    
>>> with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
...     samples = groupby(f, key=lambda k, line=count(): next(line)//100)
...     for i in samples:
...       print i
... 
(0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f174f170c50>)
(1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f1740804f50>)
(2, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f174f170c50>)
(3, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f1740804f50>)
(4, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f174f170c50>)
(5, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f1740804f50>)
(6, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f174f170c50>)
(7, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f1740804f50>)
(8, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f174f170c50>)
(9, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f1740804f50>)
```